# PHP - Using preg_replace() Only Specific Part Of String

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I have a string, for example:

```
-Website URL***Image URL
```

I want to use `preg_replace()` to replace the `***Image URL` with an empty string, look like string here:

```
-Website URL
```

I always have problem with `preg_replace()`.

Please help me! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Do you want to get substring before 3 stars?

Comment: @splash58 Yes, I do

Comment: `list($res,) = explode('***', '-Website URL***Image URL', 2);
 echo $res;`

Comment: @chris85 I don't know what to write regex. I want to substring after 3 starts

Comment: @splash58 Thank you very much but can you replace character (-) before Website URL with an empty string? Thank you!

Comment: i've written the answer

Comment: So the question wasn't `I want to use preg_replace() to replace the ***Image URL`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all after the minus at string beginning and till 3 stars

```
$res = preg_replace('/^-?(.+)\*{3}.+$/', '\1', '-Website URL***Image URL');
echo $res;
```

Comment: Can you help me what to use preg_replace reverse string above? Mean is replace -Website URL*** with an empty string and only show Image URL string. Thank you

Comment: `$res = preg_replace('/^.+\*{3}/', '', '-Website URL***Image URL');`

Comment: How to fix it? Please tell me

Comment: @Cool describe what doesn't work? No idea what your actual question here is/was, your description and this answer don't match.

Answer (score 0):

A regex to find 3 `*`s then everything else (excluding new lines) would be:

```
/\*{3}.*/
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nX9dC7/1

The `*` needs to be escaped because it is a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) in regex otherwise. The `{}` allows for a set number (or range) of the previous character/group. The `.` is any character (excluding new line) and the `*` means zero or more occurrences of the previous character/group.

PHP Usage:

```
echo preg_replace('/\*{3}.*/', '', '-Website URL***Image URL');
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/595726

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me again? This is replace character (-) before Website URL with an empty string?

Comment: What do you mean by `replace character`?